# Random variable $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $λ=1$. Let $Z =\lfloor x\rfloor$. What is the distribution of $Z$.

Tags: probability

Random variable $X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $λ=1$. Let $Z = \lfloor X\rfloor$. What is the distribution of $Z$?

I have a question if i think correctly.

We can say that $Z$ has discrete distribution, so it can't have pdf?

And the distribution of $Z$ is $P(Z=k)=P(k \leq X<k+1)=P(X<k+1) - P(X<k)$ and by continuity we have:
$P(Z=k)=1-e^{-k-1}-1+e^{-k}$

And i have the distribution of Z, it is correct?

Comment: In my opinion, your reasoning is completely correct. Except some of the $Z$ should be $X$, I have contributed an edit for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(Z=k) &= e^{-k}-e^{-k-1}\\
&= e^{-k}\left(1-e^{-1}\right)
\end{align}

It follows Geometric distribution which start from $0$.